# Can someone help me figure out how to use execute to summon a mob at a player with a name?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've tried to use:

```
{CustomName:['<name>']}
```

but it doesn't work. What should I use instead? Plz help me.

Answer (score 2):

`CustomName` is a string rather than a list containing a string. Thus, the data should look like: `{CustomName:"<NAME>"}`

Your full command should look like:

```
/execute <PLAYER SELECTOR> ~ ~ ~ /summon <MOB TYPE> ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:"<NAME>"}
```

Comment: To add an example for people newer to Minecraft: `/execute @p ~ ~ ~ /summon minecraft:armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:"SirBenet"}` (for Minecraft 1.11).

Comment: @user3-14159265359 does current Minecraft require named keys in a {} to be enclosed in quotes?

Comment: @KatieakaCtrl-Alt-Cuteness NBT keys can't be enclosed in quotes.

Comment: @SirBenet thank you for reminding me... I blame the mix of Minecraft, JSON, and Python's `dict` type for constantly confusing me...

Comment: Oh that makes sense thx ;D